# How to generate CSV file in Java from the List where List has compound class

Tags: java, csv, export-to-csv, opencsv

I have following Java class and list as:-

```
   class Person{
        String name;
        int age;
        Address address;

    }

    class Address{
        String street;
        String post_code;
        String city;
        String country;
    }

    List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
```

I would like to generate s CSV file from the list. I could easily do it if there were not compound class hariacy. Can you please suggest how can I do it? I tried opencsv and filed to do it. Opencsv works for noncompound class. I might have done something wrong. So code example will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSV= "Comma Separated Values".
You can create by yourself a csv file. You could write in the file values separated with a comma (or semi-colon). those values are cells of one row. a row is over wenn you write a line separator.

hier is a simple and basic sample of how to write rows in a csv format:

```
public static final char CSV_SEPARATOR = ';'; // it could be a comma or a semi colon

try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("my_file.csv"))) {
    personList.forEach(person -> {
        writer.append(person.getName()).append(CSV_SEPARATOR)
              .append(person.getAge()).append(CSV_SEPARATOR)
              .append(persone.getAddress().getStreet()).append(CSV_SEPARATOR)
              .append(persone.getAddress().getpostCode()).append(CSV_SEPARATOR)
              .append(persone.getAddress().getCity()).append(CSV_SEPARATOR)
              .append(persone.getAddress().getCountry()).append(System.lineSeparator());
    });
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

but for your case, I would define an interface CsvPrintable

```
public interface CsvPrintable {
   String printCsv();
}
```

then, classes Person and Address implements this interface

```
class Person implements CsvPrintable {

String name;
int age;
Address address;

@Override
printCsv() {
   return StringBuilder().append(name).append(CSV_SEPARATOR)
                         .append(age).append(CSV_SEPARATOR)
                         .append(address.printCsv()).toString();
   }
}
```

You should do the same thing with Address.

then we can improve the first code block:

```
personList.forEach(person -> {
        writer.append(person.printCsv()).append((System.lineSeparator());
    });
```

Comment: Actually, I posted some simple code get some idea. The actual object is much more complex than the given code. I need both json and csv file. I can easily generate json by Jackson api. I found Jackson has also csv here https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text/tree/master/csv. But it ways it can work for POJOs. I don't know will this work for a complex objeect?

Answer (score 0):

Define a new class, for example PersonWithAddress that includes all fields from Person and Address. Transform your Person List into a PersonWithAddress List. Now, you can give openCSV what it wants.

Comment: Actually, I posted some simple code get some idea. The actual object is much more complex than the given code. I need both json and csv file. I can easily generate json by Jackson api. I found Jackson has also csv here https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text/tree/master/csv. But it ways it can work for POJOs. I don't know will this work for a complex objeect?